# python,sympyでinit_printing(order='rev-lex')が効かない

Tags: python, sympy

**ソースコード**

```
from sympy import Symbol, pprint, init_printing

def print_series(n):
    # 次数の低い順から並べる
    init_printing(order='rev-lex')
    x = Symbol('x')
    series = x
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        series = series + (x**i)/i
    pprint(series)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input('数字を入れてください'))
    print_series(n)
```

---

**実行結果**

```
数字を入れてください 5

 5    4    3    2    
x    x    x    x     
── + ── + ── + ── + x
5    4    3    2
```

`init_printing(order='rev-lex')`が効いてないみたいなのですが、原因わかる方いらっしゃれば教えてください。よろしくです!!
`x + x^2/2 + x^3/3 + ....`という風に表示したいです。

macOS siera を使ってます。

Comment: `pprint(series, order='rev-lex')` とすればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 解決しましたありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis 以前にも何度かお伝えしていますが、**質問への回答** はコメントではなく実際の回答として投稿してください。もし信用度が増えるのを避けてのことなら「コミュニティwiki」としての投稿も検討してください。